# How do I set build rules for a file using autotools (automake, configure, etc.)?

Tags: autotools, configure, automake

I have inherited code that is set up to be built using autotools, but I've always used CMake. Some of the C++ source uses C++11 and C++14 standards. However, when I run

```
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++14" ./configure
make
```

only some of the C++ source files are being built with the `-std=c++14` flag. If this was a simple Makefile and I noticed that `foo.cc` was not built with the correct flags, I might look to change

```
foo.o: foo.cc foo.h
    $(CXX) -c foo.c
```

to

```
foo.o: foo.cc foo.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c foo.c
```

Is there an analog to this in autotools? I've checked `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` but haven't found the solution.

Comment: Do you actually see foo.o rules in `Makefile.am`? There should be none, because automake does that by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing, setting `CXXFLAGS` when calling configure, ought to work. However, often Makefile.am authors make the mistake of setting `CXXFLAGS` inside the makefile, which overrides your setting, rather than setting `AM_CXXFLAGS` as they should. That might be the case here.

In any case, if your program requires C++14, then you should probably check out the `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX([14])` macro, and put it in your configure.ac, rather than setting flags.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `CXXFLAGS` was already defined with another `-std=...` you need to execute the configure script in this way instead:

`./configure CXXFLAGS=" -std=c++14"`

Note that @ptomato is right about the difference between `AM_CXXFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.